# H10 error when trying to deploy Python app to heroku

Tags: python, heroku, web-deployment

I get a H10 error when I try to deploy my python app to Heroku. I have a Procfile and requirements.txt, I don't know the cause of the problem. I use the python web framework [Quart](https://github.com/pgjones/quart), if that can make a difference.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to post a code sample in order to be sure, but if you just followed the Quickstart and called `app.run()`, note that the process only binds to `localhost`, which is NOT visible to the Heroku runtime. You have to bind to an address visible to Heroku within 60 seconds. Try `app.run(host='0.0.0.0')` instead.

Comment: @bimsapi, the H10 error persists after implementing the suggested changes, is there any other possible cause?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing more information - h10 means that the app crashed or never bound to the port that Heroku provided. Can you post logs? E.g., the output from `heroku logs` or your Procfile? Also, I missed that you should specify the port, too: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ['PORT'])`. Quart binds to port 5000 by default, but Heroku tells your app which port to use via the `PORT` environment variable.

Comment: @bimsapi, I noticed 2 things strange in the logs, first, the H10 error: `at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dertio.herokuapp.com request_id=d54fb4a2-3ef7-4582-a26f-15bb59426464 fwd="24.64.141.65" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https`, 

second, this: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Comment: That's a little more to go on. That's a Python error - if your code is trying to import app or something similar. Can you share 1) the Procfile 2) your filesystem layout, and 2) the code that configures/launches the Quart app in your code? You don't have to share the route functions.

Comment: @bimsapi, my Procfile consists of `web: gunicorn app:app`. My file layout looks like this: `\Desktop\app\main_loop.py` (note the app file isn't     actually named app). The code that launches the app is this: 

`if __name__ == '__main__':
    
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ['PORT']`.

Comment: @bimsapi, I just noticed an error when i run the program normally: `app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ['PORT']))
  File "C:\Users\vance\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\os.py", line 669, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PORT'`

Comment: Re: KeyError: sorry, use `os.environ.get('PORT', '5000')`. That will return default port "5000" if the env var `PORT` doesn't exist. Re: file. Try it as: `web:gunicorn main_loop:app` (assuming you are in the `app` dir). The `foo:bar` param is `module:var`, where you can think of "module" as a file path, without the .py extension. It's actually more complex than that, but that's an ok mental model to start out.

Comment: @bimsapi, I still get this error: `TypeError: __call__() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given`.